# Query SQL Server database from C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to query the database and get it to return the correct data using the data that the user passes into the get request on my web API.

I have tried using:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
con.Open();

if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
}
```

However, I am unsure of what I need the put in the command. Do I just write something like this:

```
WHERE forename, surname, caseid, postcode, telephone, email FROM TestDB.crm-data
```

Or am I mistaken?

This is the full code sorry

```
public string Get(string forename, string surname, int? caseid, int? loanid, string postcode, string telephone, string email, string title)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
    con.Open();

    if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM crm-base WHERE forename");
    }
}
```

Comment: `WHERE forename, surname, caseid, postcode, telephone, email FROM TestDB.crm-data ` ?? did you mean `SELECT forename, surname, caseid, postcode, telephone, email FROM TestDB.crm-data ` ?

Comment: You miss some element before "WHERE"

Comment: @EmanuelPirovano I mean is that what is supposed to go inside of sqlcommand()

Comment: @BagusTesa  I mean is that what is supposed to go inside of sqlcommand()

Comment: So you have to read a guide about sql command, a where want always a conditions , e.g. b=3 ...

Comment: @EmanuelPirovano so i would do WHERE forename=forename as forename is a param in the get request

Comment: Okay, first tell us what does the user input...

Comment: The basic structure of an sql query is this: `SELECT <columnsList> FROM <tableName> [WHERE <conditions>]`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled do I put the <> around my params or is that just you example

Comment: This is just an example. instead of `<columnsList>` you should use the actual columns - `SELECT forename, surname, caseid FROM...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not perfect but here you go. You have already done part of it:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    con.Open();

    var query=@"Select forename, surname, caseid, postcode, telephone, email 
                FROM TestDB.crm-data WHERE caseid=@caseId OR email=@email";

    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@caseid",SqlDbType.Int).Value=1234;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Value="user@example.com";
        var dtb=new DataTable();
        var da=new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        da.Fill(dtb)
        //NOW dtb CONTAINS RECORDS FROM YOUR QUERY
    }
}
```

Comment: so i can just do return dtb?

Comment: @andywilson Yes, you can return data-table. But please use updated method to add parameters.

Comment: @marc_s what would you use instead of addwithvalue is there a short inline way?

Comment: @andywilson I have updated the answer. You need to take care of data type for your parameters and names etc.

Comment: @andywilson: use the call `Parameters.Add("@paramname", <datatype>)` to **explicitly** define the parameter's data type. If you use `.AddWithValue`, then ADO.NET has to *guess* what datatype you might be using - it gets it right quite often - but not always - so I think you should always use the call that **explicitly defines** the datatype of the parameter - just to be 100% safe

Comment: @marc_s It is giving me an error that it doesnt know what @ forename is i know the issue is that its not using DBNull is there a way i can do this inline rather than an if else statement

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot It is giving me an error that it doesnt know what @ forename is i know the issue is that its not using DBNull is there a way i can do this inline rather than an if else statement

Answer (score 0):

You could use a raw query if your query has constant parameters. However, if you are passing in different values for the parameters (in your where clause) - use SQLParameters. These are built to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Look at this link for some examples.

http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06

Comment: How would i do that with multiple parameters and also passed in through a get request as that doesn't tell me how i need to be able to do it that tells me how to do it with local parameters

Comment: You should include some code into your answer to illustrate main point in the linked article/blog post/fiddle etc.

Answer (score -1):

Your query is not complete. You added a where clause without specifiyng the condition.

you need to do something similar to this;

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM crm-base WHERE forename='{forename}');
```

This will grab all records with the forename equals to the one passed into the get method.

Comment: Don't use string concatenation - use **explicit parameters** - to **avoid SQL injection attacks!**